# ScrollHeight size of execute_script() with python selenium returns a unchanged result

Tags: python, selenium

**Code:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Image contents is my current code. My objective is to get all video's data in youtube channel. But currently I got only 30 initial video data. After performing logic once, it finishes. In other words newHeight's size equeals lastHeght's size. Definitely, `execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")` code correctly performed once. Why do this result occur?

```
class Channel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.channelId = ''
        self.Home = ''
        self.Home_title = ''
        self.videoTab = ''
        self.chromedriver = '../chromedriver.exe'
        self.chromeBrowser = webdriver.Chrome(self.chromedriver)

    def __del__(self):
        self.chromeBrowser.quit()

def getVideoData(self):
    self.chromeBrowser.get(self.videoTab)
    lastHeight = self.chromeBrowser.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
    print('lastHeight : ' + str(lastHeight))
    while True:
        self.chromeBrowser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")
        self.chromeBrowser.implicitly_wait(0.5)
        newHeight = self.chromeBrowser.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
        print('newHeight : ' + str(newHeight))
        if newHeight == lastHeight:
            break
        lastHeight = newHeight
    page = self.chromeBrowser.page_source
    html = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    for href in html.select('#thumbnail'):
        href.get('href')
    for video_title in html.select('#video-title'):
        print(video_title.text)
    print(len(html.select('#video-title')))
```

Comment: share code/output as text, not as image

Comment: [@Andersson] Sorry, Andersson. I am not familiar with stackoverflow. So all code can't show to a code style.  I don't understand why code are showed above.
Please understand.